# Spontaneous combustion of npm - code Z_DATA_ERROR

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a production site (linux) and local (Mac ARM1) both running on the same versions of node and npm, until all that follows. The local broke with no change of code on my part. When I try to run npm install, I get

```
code Z_DATA_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -3
npm ERR! zlib: incorrect data check
```

The production site is running node 14.21.3 and npm 6.14.18. I've tried

- removing npm and reinstalling
- clearing npm cache, killing node_modules and removing package lock
- downgrading npm to 6.14.15
- downgrading node to 14.17.6 (via nvm)

all based on various recommendations. Same problem. I'm guessing that were I to rerun npm install on the production site, I'd end up in the same place as I have on the local.